# How to create a package with a python file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, package, deb

Hello I have this python file main.py like this :

```
print "a"
```

This file is really simple and I would like to create a deb file for this python file. Then I would like when I type for instance main in the terminal when the package is installed main I get :

a

Thank you very much !

Comment: Do you want to know how to create a deb file, or how you can type `main` and run the python script?

Comment: please try to rephrase your posting as a question. dont list all the things you want to do. explicitly ask how to do X. also tell us what you have already tried and why you are struggeling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If you want to run main.py from the command line:

In your `main.py` you need to add a python [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "a"
```

In a terminal navigate to where your file is saved and run the following commands:

```
chmod +x main.py
sudo cp main.py ~/bin/
```

Now you can type `main.py` on the terminal and your command should run. If you rename your file to `main`, then you'll only have to type `main` to get it to run.

### If you actually want to create a deb package:

If you actually want to create a deb file, then follow [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=910717) link.